# How can I loop through two different models on one route

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I am trying to loop through two different models on a single route. What is best practice to do this?

Currently I am trying:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return App.Player.find();
    },
    setupController: function(controller, model){
        controller.set('eventRounds', App.eventRound.find());
    }
});
```

And looping though it with:

```
{{#each eventRounds}}
       <tr> 
           <td>{{ player_1 }}</td>
           <td>{{ player_2 }}</td>
       </tr>
{{/each}}
```

But the setupController seems to be breaking the first model as well.

Thanks!

Comment: difficult to tell what you're trying to do... you tagged this with handlebars, so I'm wondering if you're really in the route or in the view layer.. please explain what you're trying to do, what have you done and what failed... or at least a conceptual explanation of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Added the code I was currently using, sorry for the delay and thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default `setupController` hook sets the `model` property of the associated controller to the route handler's model.

When you define it manually, it will override the default behaviour.

So in your setupController, call `this._super()` or set the `model` manually, before you do your stuff.

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return App.Player.find();
    },
    setupController: function(controller, model){
        controller.set('model', model);
        controller.set('eventRounds', App.eventRound.find());
    }
});
```

Comment: I added the controller.set('model', model); Am I correctly trying to call it and loop through it with handlebars?